# SQLite: db.update with composite primary key?

Tags: sqlite

I'm quite new to Android programming, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to build an SQLite database with two tables. In one of the tables I'm using a composite primary key on two columns. My question is how to write the update function. I want to say "update contact where id1 = x and id2 = y", how do I do that?

The example I'm following looks like this:

```
public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("phone", phone);
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        contentValues.put("street", street);
        contentValues.put("place", place);
        db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? and id2 = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(id), Integer.toString(id2) } );
```

Of course, you'd need to pass in or define id2 somewhere.